# Ubuntu 14.04 no sound neither headfones nor laptop speaker

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

Ubuntu 14.04 no sound neither headphones nor laptop speaker.

I've no other operating system installed details attached.

I've removed & reinstall the alsamixer & stuffs. I also installed audio dkms packages.

My Rthymbox vlc shows it's playing but no sounds can be heard.

I got HDA Intel MID sound card are attached details.

Screenshots
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To check the sound configuration install pavucontrol for pulseaudio:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Now start it and check if the output has the right configuration, it might be something like `audio duplex`

Check if the output device is muted and also check that the application use the right sound card. Could you add screen shots to your posts from pavucontrol?